# Seamlessly swapping Activity and Service and back

Tags: android

I want to start a service once my activity is put in the background (home button is pressed, or the activity is interrupted in any other way), and stop the service once my activity is back in the foreground.

Placing the start and stop of the service in any of the Activity lifecycle callbacks (starting in onPause and stopping in onResume, for example) isn't very good, since they are being called also on orientation change, and I don't want to start the service and immediately stop it.

Also, I don't want to run the service in the background all the time, but only when the activity is not visible.

What is the best practice for this use case?

Comment: Why do you need this structure? It's common way of handling service+activities: Service runs always, and activity binds on it

Comment: It's for an animated countdown app, so I need an animation thread only when it's visible, and a different thread for the service to update a custom notification when it's in the background. I never need both cases simultaneously, so it would be a waste of resources to keep the service running all the time.

Comment: Actually for this purpose it's better to have service with timer, and activity(if there is one) asks service for current value and shows it. You will never see waste of resources - it's just too small.

Comment: The service also runs a (sort of) animation - it's updating the custom notification (a RemoteView) so it is a waste to run unneeded, and the timer by itself has no added value, because a simple long variable is enough for the Activity to know where to continue from when resumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onPause and onResume are still the best practice. If you're concerned about short-term events such as orientation change, in your onPause, set a timer... when the timer expires, start the service, and cancel the timer in onResume.

Comment: thanks. I was considering a timer, but was hoping there's a more elegant solution

Comment: another alternative, though not too clean for your purpose I think, is to catch your own orientation change signal and deal with it yourself; this will not cause you to pause/resume but it's left to you to deal with the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering my own question, but rather documenting here a research I've done, and the reason why I think timer is a better solution (therefore I accepted mah's suggestion).
Hope this will help someone else trying to solve this, and it may also help solve different problems.

My idea was to capture configuration change using Application class, add a timestamp if it was changed, and check in onPause() if there just been a configuration change - and if there has been - don't start the service.

It didn't work out because of two reasons:

1. it took a surprisingly long time between onConfigurationChange() and onPause() - about 500ms. (tested on Galaxy S), so I needed to use a long threshold.
2. with a long threshold there is a big chance that the user hit the home button right after a configuration change (orientation, keyboard pulled, etc). So the app would exit without the service starting, and that's not acceptable.

For reference, this is the code:

```
public class RealPauseApp extends Application {

    Configuration oldConfig = null;
    private long configChangedAt;
    private static final int CONFIG_TIME_THRESHOLD = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (oldConfig != null) {
            Log.v("#",
                    "onConfigurationChanged: " + newConfig.diff(oldConfig));
            if (newConfig.diff(oldConfig) > 0) {
                configChangedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("#", "oldConfig is null");
        }
        oldConfig = newConfig;

    }

    public boolean didConfigJustChanged() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - configChangedAt < CONFIG_TIME_THRESHOLD) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

and the relevant part in the Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("++++", "onResume: ** will stop any service here **");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!((RealPauseApp) getApplication()).didConfigJustChanged()) {
        // NO CONFIG CHANGE - It means that we're really pausing
        Log.v("----", "onPause: ** will start the service here **");
    } else {
        // CONFIG CHANGED - No need to start service

        // * POSSIBLE FALSE NEGATIVE * - if config was indeed changed
        // and just after that the activity was really paused
    }
}
```

So it's not a good solution for my problem - but still a helpful experiment.
It may be relevant to someone as a reference.